# Is use of while loop in stored procedure causing System.OutOfMemoryException?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, out-of-memory, temp-tables

I have been struggling with **System.OutOfMemoryException**. I have seen some solution but all are saying you need more RAM.I doubt if it is due to inefficiency of code.So let me share my problem.
I have 10 different tables with around 5k records in each, I need to select one column from each table and construct a new table.I am able to insert around 1.5k records but then execution stop with **"System.OutOfMemoryException"** .
My while loop looks like

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Sp_sample
As 
    Select col1
    into
    #ControlTable
    from 
    tab1

while exists(select * from #ControlTable)
    begin

            (select count(*) from #ControlTable);
            select @var1 = (select top 1 col1 from #ControlTable);          
            select @var2 = (select top 1 col2 from table1 where col3=@var1);
            if exists (select a from tablenew where col1=@var1)
            begin               
                update tablenew set col2 = @var2 where col1 = @var1
            end
            else
            begin           
                insert into tablenew values (@var1,@var2)
            end
            delete from #ControlTable where col1 = @var1;   
    end
Begin
```

I have posted sample code to make question more generic.
Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You mean `select @var1 = (select top 1 col1 from #ControlTable);`?

Comment: I feel like you are overpowering this task that would be easily done with a [Merge Statement](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx) Also, there are parts of it that do no good like `(select count(*) from #ControlTable);`

Comment: Agree with Jorge - that `(select count(*) from #ControlTable);` is going to be generating a separate *result set* every time the loop iterates. So if you're talking about 5000 rows you'll be generating 5000 result sets for the client system to deal with.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever. I replaced it, now i am comparing index as below answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below while loop and check performance:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Sp_sample
As 
Select col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order By col1) AS RowNo
into
#ControlTable
from 
tab1

DECLARE @Index INT=1;
DECLARE @TotalRow INT=0;

SELECT @TotalRow=COUNT(col1) FROM #ControlTable

while @Index<=@TotalRow
begin            
        select @var1 =  var1 from #ControlTable where RowNo=@Index;          
        select @var2 = var2 from table1 where col1=@var1;

        if exists (select a from tablenew where col1=@var1)
        begin               
            update tablenew set col2 = @var2 where col1 = @var1
        end
        else
        begin           
            insert into tablenew values (@var1,@var2)
        end
        SET @Index = @Index+1;
end
Begin
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `MERGE` to insert or update table.

```
Select col1, max(col2) AS col2 into #ControlTable from  tab1 GROUP BY col1

MERGE tablenew  AS T
USING #ControlTable AS S
ON (T.col1 = S.col1) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
   THEN INSERT(col1, col2) VALUES(S.col1, S.col2)
WHEN MATCHED 
   THEN UPDATE SET T.col2 = S.col2
```